# Webhooks do not work for the Sandbox environment of Maya

Tags: webhooks, sandbox, maya-business

I've tried integrating [Maya Checkout](https://developers.maya.ph/reference/createv1checkout) using the [Sandbox credentials](https://developers.maya.ph/reference/sandbox-credentials-and-cards#sandbox-api-keys) for the **public** and **secret** API keys. The endpoint worked well with these credentials.

However, the problem was that **Maya** does not send HTTP Requests to the Webhook endpoint we prepared on our application. What could have I missed here? How to make the webhooks work for the sandbox environment?

Comment: Is your application publicly accessible for Maya to speak to? If not, you can look at using ngrok to integrate your application with their sandbox environment.

Answer (score 0):

also pay attention to the webhost and the domain on which the webhook is listening, you're app may be publicly accessible but not accepting because of the webhost or the origin header

they might be permission problem as well. request is dropped before doing the expecting thing because of

- Firewall on localcomputer
- Access Control Layer of the webhook's framework

i advise you for testing purpose to "allow everything" just to check if its permission problem